# Linear combination of regression coefficients in R

Tags: r, regression, linear-regression

I need to run a multiple regression in R, with the variables X1, X2 and X3, where there is a variable θ = β2 + β3.
So instead of β2, for the coefficient of X2 I need to use (θ - β3). How could I do this?

Comment: Are you saying theta is known, i.e., you have a constraint on beta2 and beta3?

Comment: Yes, I am supposed to the test the hypothesis that theta = (β2 + β3) > 0.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that Y = b1 * x1 + (t - b3) * x2 + b3 * x3

is equivalent to

Y = b1 * x1 + t * x2 - b3 * x2 + b3 * x3 = b1 * x1 + t * x2 + b3 * (x3 - x2)

So, you can continue from there easily.

Comment: Would I have to define t as t = x2+x3 in my code? When I try to do this, it says "object 'x2' not found"

Comment: I think then you just fit it normally. So your code should be `df$new_col <- (df$x3 - df$x2)` then `lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + new_col, data=df)`

Comment: I am getting the following error: Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp* , new_col, value = integer(0)) : 
  replacement has 0 rows, data has 1

Comment: What is your data frame called? Is it empty? Are the values non-numeric? Give me more information

Comment: Sorry, I'm brand new to this so I'm still really struggling with the basics - I'm using data from an excel doc, I called it mydata and the values are all numeric. There are 6 columns that contain numbers only - x1, x2, x3, x4, u and y

Comment: Try `mydata$new_col <- (mydata$x3 - mydata$x2)` then `lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + new_col, data=mydata)`

Comment: That worked for creating the new variable, thanks so much. However, when I run the regression, I get the same values for theta as I did for x2. Instead, I need a coefficient estimate for theta = (b2 + b3) which I assume has to be different than b2. I made another variable to use for the coefficient for x2, mydata$new_col2 <- (mydata$new_col - mydata$x3) but it is returning the same values I already had.

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't really understand. You should do `model <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3)` and then do `summary(model)` and compare the coefficients from that summary to doing `model2 <- lm(y ~ x1 + x2 + new_col` then `summary(model2)`. The coefficient for `x2` in `model2` should be your value of theta. Are the coefficients the same values as what you already had?

Comment: Oh I see now, thank you so much.